# test timestamp in ALSA: How to preload the sound sample into the buffer?

Tags: timestamp, alsa

Since the "buffer" should store the "information" from the cpu and then send the command to audio device in order to play sound, I need to preload the sound sample into the "buffer" to test the timestamp between the buffer and audio device.

How can I preload the sound sample into the buffer?

Comment: You just write the data into the buffer.

Comment: @CL. Thank you. I am also wondering that if I preload the sound sample into the buffer, how to issue command to let the audio play. I mean which function to play the audio??

Comment: This is what the [start threshold](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html#pcm_sw_params) is for.